# AJAX call not receiving a response from webserver

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js

I've looked at related questions and none have helped me. I am therefore creating this question.

So my client decrypts URLs and sends them to my server, which then decrypts them and makes an API call using the decrypted request. On the server side everything seems to be working fine. No errors are being thrown. Logs seem fine etc.

My AJAX looks like:

```
var handleRequest = function(request){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: host + '/requests?call=' + request,
        success: function(data) {
        var rawJSON = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
        console.log('Recieved: ' + rawJSON);
        editor.setValue(rawJSON);
       },
       error: function(jqXHR, responseText,status){
            console.log(jqXHR.responseText)
       },
       dataType: 'jsonp'
    });
}
```

Server side:

```
app.get('/requests', function(req, res) {
    var call = req.query.call;
    var decryptedRequest = decryptRequest(call);
    console.log("Recieved: " + decryptedRequest);

    var rawJson = retriever.makeExternalCall(decryptedRequest);
    console.log('Sending response to client');

    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.send(rawJson);
});
```

Method used above:

```
var requestService = require('request');

module.exports = {
    makeExternalCall: function(url) {
        console.log('Making call to: ' + url);
        requestService(url, function(error, response, body){
            console.log(body);
            return body;
        });
    }
}
```

Strangely when I replace

```
res.send(rawJson);
```

with

```
res.send('hello');
```

I get a response. Any ideas on what is going on here?

Comment: The `makeExternalCall` function doesn't return anything. Which means `rawJson` is undefined. This is an extremely common issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Hmmm that was an issue I had already though I addressed @ChrisG . I am not from a functional programming background so this is a rookie mistake on my part. I guess I can just return the function?

Comment: (The solution is to move `res.send()` to where you currently have `return body;`)

Comment: Isn't it good practice to send a response in the request handler. i.e. app.get(.....)?

Comment: probably your `requestService` haven't returned the response yet but your code already called `res.send(rawJson)`. That's how asynchronous calls work.

Comment: @MrSpartacus Yes it is, but not if it's impossible to do so. That's simply how node.js works. It's all asynchronous and callbacks. Did you not read the page I linked?

Comment: If you try to set a timeout enough to wait for the response, that might also work before it fires `res.send(rawJson)`,

Comment: Sorry I will have a proper read of that now @ChrisG . Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `makeExternalCall` is an async function. Returning from callback doesn't work as the async function has already returned before returning the data and hence `rawJson` `is undefined`.

Solution to this is proper usage of the callback.

```
var requestService = require('request');

module.exports = {
    makeExternalCall: function(url,callback) {
        console.log('Making call to: ' + url);
        requestService(url, callback);
    }
}
```

And then in API handler

```
app.get('/requests', function(req, res) {
    var call = req.query.call;
    var decryptedRequest = decryptRequest(call);
    console.log("Recieved: " + decryptedRequest);

    retriever.makeExternalCall(decryptedRequest, function(error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
            res.send("error message");
        } else {
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            res.send(body);
        }
    })
});
```